# Find whole value without using LIKE operator

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a large number to find in a table. But only a little part of it is given to me to find the whole number. I am looking for some new way to find these out without using the `like` operator. I know it is a simple thing, but I need a new approach.

- Value given is:  `4213076600`
- Value to find is:  `89013106904213076600`

I want to find it in the following query:

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    table_name 
WHERE   column_name in (value,value,value)
```

i have searched the websites for this and came to know about the left() and right() functions but don't know how to arrange them to get the result

Comment: Why can't you use `like`? Also, I think you omitted a critical requirement. Are you to search for *more than one* partial value?

Comment: ya i need to search more than one value that's why i need to use 'in' function

Comment: No, [`IN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177682%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) will not work here. It only finds exact matches. If you need a partial match, you must use `like` (or something similar). ie `WHERE col LIKE '%aaa%' OR col LIKE '%bbb%'`.

Comment: ya i know that approach but right now i have discussed this matter with my one of my colleagues and there's an other way .. i came to know about ..

Comment: Are the partial values always the same length and/or always in the same position? For example, at the end 8901310690_4213076600_

Comment: yes they are always the same length and mostly from the end

Comment: What do you mean by "mostly"? If it can be anywhere in the string, then `right` will not work all of the time.

Comment: sometimes the value given is from the mid section that's what i meant by the mostly

Comment: If it can be anywhere in the string, I do not think you can avoid using multiple `like` statements or something similar. BTW, if your colleague said there is another way, why do they not just tell you what it is?

Comment: i have posted the query the way it works with the 'in' clause

Comment: Right, but like I mentioned `IN` only finds exact matches. It cannot be used to find partial matches that can be *anywhere* in the string (start, middle or end).

Comment: but its getting the full column value by giving it the partial value form start or end at the place of 'value'

Comment: can you change the structure of the table you are searching?

Comment: *but its getting the full column value* Not possible. `IN` checks for equality. The query you posted `WHERE Col IN ('4213076600')` would **not** return the value `89013106904213076600` nor would it find 4213076600 *anywhere* in the whole value.

Comment: @faizan I think you've misunderstood how 'IN' works - it checks to see if a specified value is 'in' a list of values, not to see if a value is contained within another value.

Comment: but have you seen my own answer it shows that how it can work

Answer (score 2):

You can use `CONTAINS` [more info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name 
WHERE CONTAINS(column_name , '"*value*"')
```

For `CONTAINS` you need to create a `FULL TEXT INDEX` [on the table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc879306%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Comment: This is a good solution if your SQL version is >= 2005, and your table is full-texted indexed.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    table_name
WHERE
    CHARINDEX(value1,column_name)>0
    OR CHARINDEX(value2,column_name)>0
    OR CHARINDEX(value3,column_name)>0
```

Comment: @faizan "its giving the empty columns" ...what do you mean? I've used `CHARINDEX` before in this context

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @table table (n varchar(20))
DECLARE @param1 varchar(20)

SET @param1 = '4213076600'

INSERT INTO @table (n)
SELECT '89013106904213076600'

SELECT n 
FROM @table
WHERE RIGHT(n, len(@param1)) = @param1
```

**Edit**

```
select * 
from table_name 
where right(column_name, len(value)) = value
```

Comment: maybe you didn't understood that ... i have to find this'89013106904213076600' from a table which already contains this value and i have got '4213076600' value to find it which is a part of above value .....

Comment: @faizan My answer was a single testable unit that anybody can throw into their sql editor and run, imagine your table replaced with my table and the column 'n' replaced with your column. Updated answer.

Comment: ya thanks that second query works but it only works for the single value ... and ... i have to find more than one in a single query like in the example i have stated

Comment: can i use both left() and right() functions in the same query ... ?

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT left(column_name,length_of_value)
FROM   table_name
WHERE  RIGHT(column_name,length_of_value_given) IN (value,value,value)
```

That's way it works for `IN` clause